# UnicodeDecodeError trying to merge all these csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob

Hi I am having trouble merging .csv files using Jupyter Notebook. The reason is that the csv files contain hex values, so when I load these csv files normally I need to use "encoding = 'latin'" I do not know how to do this when I am using the glob module. Here is the code that I am using. ByDistrict79 is the name of all the csv files and they will load, the issue is with pd.concat where I am getting the error code, thank you. Also the structure of the files are all the same.

**My Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

stock_files = sorted(glob('ByDistrict79_*.csv'))
stock_files

pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename = file)
          for file in stock_files),ignore_index =True)
```

**Error Code**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 14: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f3eb9c7dddcd> in <module>
      1 pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename = file)
----> 2           for file in stock_files),ignore_index =True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    253         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    254         copy=copy,
--> 255         sort=sort,
    256     )
    257 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    299             objs = [objs[k] for k in keys]
    300         else:
--> 301             objs = list(objs)
    302 
    303         if len(objs) == 0:

<ipython-input-3-f3eb9c7dddcd> in <genexpr>(.0)
      1 pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename = file)
----> 2           for file in stock_files),ignore_index =True)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    461 
    462     try:
--> 463         data = parser.read(nrows)
    464     finally:
    465         parser.close()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1152     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1153         nrows = _validate_integer("nrows", nrows)
-> 1154         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1155 
   1156         # May alter columns / col_dict

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   2057     def read(self, nrows=None):
   2058         try:
-> 2059             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   2060         except StopIteration:
   2061             if self._first_chunk:

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas read_csv() function accepts an optional encoding parameter.  The revised function call would be: `pd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin-1')`

Also, the `UnicodeDecodError` suggests there may be a byte-order mark (BOM) in the file.